# Importing sub-template doesn't work in Liquex (Elixir library)

Tags: elixir

I'm using the Elixir `Liquex` version 0.7 template library.

I have the following `render` function:

```
def render(template, params) do
    path = "/the/path/to/the/template.html"
    {str, _} = File.read!(path)
    |> Liquex.parse!()
    |> Liquex.render!(params)
    Enum.join(str)
  end
```

All goes OK if the template if simple:

```
<center>
  <b>Hello</b> World {{ name }}.
</center>
```

But if I want to include a sub-template, as for exemple

```
<center>
  <b>Hello</b> World {{ name }}.
</center>

{% render "footer" %}
```

(or `{% render "footer.html" %}`)

where, `footer` is

```
<hr>
This is the footer
```

I get the following error: `** (Plug.Conn.WrapperError) ** (Liquex.Error) This liquid context does not allow includes.`